# Show all Category & Sub- Category in a particular page like as sitemap

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am New to opencart. I Just want to show all Category & Sub- Category in a

particular page like as sitemap, Which is liked by my Boss.

Comment: I tried to change in category page(i.e catalog/ controller/module/category.php) like as sitemap. But it also not working

Comment: okay let me write the code.

Comment: Hi Ali, I posted that code. I just list-out all the category & Subcategory in a particular category page like as sitemap.

Comment: Site map is not a category page. It is an information page. You will have to make a new page. A page has 4 parts. Controller, model, Language and tpl file.

Comment: Yes Ali, I Understand. But I want to show one of my category page like as sitemap page

Comment: Ali, I Posted My Question. Plz. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784327/opencart-i-want-to-change-data-fetching-display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this code. Just paste it in your desired controller.

```
$data['categories'] = array();

$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category['name'] . '<br/>';
    $children_data = array();
    $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        echo ' --- ' . $child['name'] . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all add this code in your `catalog/controller/common/header.php` and check is it working?

Comment: wow... hands off to you ali. Its working, but i have one more trouble, :(

Comment: What's the issue? Ask me.

Comment: Do you want the number of items too? And links also?

Comment: Okay wait. Let me try it.

Comment: Open admin panel. Go in `Layouts`, edit `Sitemap`, Add New module `Category`, `Position Left` and Sort `1`.

Comment: No Ali, I Just Need to show the category in left side which you told to add catalog/controller/common/header.php

Comment: Add me on skype. My skype id is `syed_ali_zia`. I will tell you what to do.

Comment: Ali, I Changed that page view as per my wishes. Boss Said OK, Good :) But Ali, My Boss gave another Trouble. I definitely want your help

Comment: Can you tick my answer?